# Not able to get Updatable and scrollable Result set in Oracle using Java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
conn=DriverManager.getConnection(URL,username,password);
String sql="select * from test where user_id='abc'";
stmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE);
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
rs.afterLast();
```

getting exception in this line, afterLast operation not allowed .

Comment: I am trying to use a scrollable resultset in java, to scroll to any position within resultset but not able to do so and getting exception.

Comment: See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm#JJDBC28612

Answer (score 2):

Reading from the [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm#JJDBC28611):-

> To produce a scroll-sensitive result set: A query cannot use SELECT * .
>
> However, there is a workaround for this.
>
> As a workaround for the SELECT * limitation, you can use table aliases, as shown in the following example:
>
> SELECT t.* FROM TABLE t ...

Change your query to `select test.* from test where user_id='abc'`

or use specific column names to retrive instead of *.